# Discoverable links to revision history

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list

I had the hardest time figuring out how to get to the revision history by links over the past few days ... it would be really nice if there was just a link named "history" next to "link", "flag", etc. to get to it. This would also make it easy to find on questions/answers that had had no edits yet.

(Oh, for anyone else trying to figure out where the links are: look at the edit date, to the left of the asking date, on questions/answers that show up as edited. For other questions/answers, use the URL template `http://<site>/posts/<PostId>/revisions`.)

Comment: As a side note, there is [a userscript](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts/blob/master/SEModifications.user.js) which adds these links, [among other things](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts/blob/master/README.md) (see bottom section).