# How can I copy code from a question to an answer?

Tags: support, code-formatting

No matter what combinations or order of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, and the `{}` button I press, I cannot seem to copy formatted code from a question to my answer. Can somebody clue me in please?

**Edit:** I'm using IE8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I typically copy the markdown source directly, instead of copying the formatted text. If the post has been edited, click the "edited X minutes ago" link to get to the revision history, and then click "view source" to get to the source. If it hasn't been edited you have to go to the revision history manually; it's at `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/POST_ID/revisions`

Comment: Ok, this works, but it seems really round about. Is this the only way?

Comment: @Thomas There's a feature request to [add a link all the time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72695/discoverable-links-to-revision-history). It's somewhat easier for 2k users, since they have an edit link they can use

Comment: @mic anonymous users can edit now, *if the post is older than 24 hours*. registered users can always edit, though the edit must be approved. FYI.

Comment: @Jeff Oh, that's a good point; I guess everyone can just use the edit link then

Comment: @Jeff, I don't see how I can edit posts older than 24 hours without approval.

Comment: @Thomas You can't, but you can get to the edit page, which lets you copy the markdown

Comment: @Thomas Install the [SEModifications](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts/raw/master/SEModifications.user.js) user script, it will add a `history` link to all posts, and does other things too. Also see the other [Stack Exchange Scripts](http://rchern.github.com/StackExchangeScripts/#install).

Comment: @Nyus, I suppose that there are no scripts available for IE8, either on IE7Pro or otherwise?

Comment: @Thomas You **can** install userscripts with IE7Pro.

Comment: @Nyus, can I use them as is, or are mods required?

Comment: @Thomas Just install it, reload SO and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The order you listed should work find, as long as you have the code selected for ctrl-k or the {} button.

Comment: Only is doesn't. The line enddings and indentation disappear.

Comment: @Thomas, so it does copy the text, just not the indentations?  Might want to mention that in your question because it just sounds like you can't copy and paste.  Regardless, I don't loose indentation when copying from a question or answer, not sure if it makes a difference but I am using Chrome instead of IE8.

Comment: I just tried Chrom and it works as expected. I like IE, but maybe Chrome is a better platform for SO.

Comment: BTW, my question refers to pasting "formatted code"

Comment: @Thomas, Just checked and it works fine in Firefox, so that is another option.  I never use IE so I haven't run into the issue you were facing.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you need to format code in a question using the curly-brace icon, you need to do the same thing in an answer.

You can preface a line of code with 4 spaces or surround a short segment with ` characters (the apostrophe-like character to the left of the 1 key).

Select a block of code and hit the curly-brace key to format the whole block.